# Ember Object as no setters nor getters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am working on an Ember 2.7 application and have a little issue.
I have a component pulling attributes from a service and then displays them in its views as they get updated. 
Here is the bit of the actual code (I know this code makes no sense in terms of purpose but it's not the point) :

component.js : this is the component that pulls and display the attributes. This component calls methods from the service providing datas that are pretty much the same (2 arrays)

export

```
default Ember.Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('xlsxInput', this.get('newUser').getXlsxInput());
    this.set('bulkNewUsers', this.get('newUser').getBulkNewUsers());
  },
  newUser: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {

    processCsvInput() {
      let arrayedCsv = csvToArray.compute(this.get('csvInput'));
      console.log("processCsvInput:", arrayedCsv);
      this.get('newUser').populateBulkNewUsers(arrayedCsv);
      this.get('newUser').setXlsNewUsers(arrayedCsv);
    },
    ...
```

service.js : this is the service that provides the attributes and methods

```
var emptyNewUser = Ember.Object.extend({
  init() {
    this._super();
  },

  visible: true
});

export default Ember.Service.extend({

  users: Ember.inject.service(),

  bulkNewUsers: [],
  xlsxInput: [],

  arrayToArObj(src, data, _that) {
    _that.get(src).arrayContentWillChange(0, null, data.length);
    var buffer = _that.get(src);
    data.forEach(function(user){
      buffer.push(emptyNewUser.create({
        firstname: user[0],
        lastname: user[1],
        email: user[2]
      }));
    });
    _that.set(src, buffer);
    _that.get(src).arrayContentDidChange();
  },
  populateBulkNewUsers(bulkArray) {
    console.log("empty bulk", this.get('bulkNewUsers'));
    this.get('arrayToArObj')('bulkNewUsers', bulkArray, this);
  },
  setXlsNewUsers(incomingArray) {
    console.log("empty xls", this.get('xlsxInput'));
    this.get('arrayToArObj')('xlsxInput', incomingArray, this);
  },
  ...
```

So both `bulkNewUsers` and `xlsxInput` change after going through the method `arrayToArObj()` but one gets updated in the component (`bulkNewUsers`), the other doesn't.

By looking closer to the attributes by console.logging them both I noticed that `bulkNewUsers` has getters and setters for each of the attributes of its objects, although `xlsxInput` doesn't have any getters not setters, its objects only have the three string properties. I assume the fact that the component can't pull `xslxInputs` comes from those getters and setters missing.

Would you know what I have done wrong ?

Comment: `csvToArray` - how are you getting this property. is it globally defined ?.,what is `compute` ? i would like to know what it is doing ?..Are you using `bulkNewUsers` property in template but not `xlsxInput` property ? am i right ?.

Comment: One of the purpose of the application is to transform csv or xls into arrays of Ember objects. is this case `csvToArray` is not relevant to the interest, it only gives an array. Compute is a method I use in a custom helper. I want to use both `bulkNewsUsers` and `xlsxInput` in my template but after going through the service method, only `bulkNewusers` gets updated in the template. As I said, after console.logging everything, I only found the getters/setters in `xlsxInput` missing.

Comment: Show us code`getXlsxInput` and `getBulkNewUsers` method in newUser service. Mean while you can try replacing `Ember.computed.alias('newUser.xlsxInput')` and `Ember.computed.alias('newUser.bulkNewUsers')` instead of setting it from init method.

Comment: `getXlsxInput` and `getBulkNewUsers` are just straight getters that only `return this.get('getXlsxInput')` and `return this.get('getBulkNewUsers')`. Concerning the alias, I'm going to give it a go ! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion kumkanillam but i had no luck, still nothing displayed using alias